# Build a filter on same node

Tags: c#, mongodb, filter

I have a problem where I need to apply a filter to an Object in my database.
Here's an example:

```
"Object": {
    "Properties" : [ 
                {
                    "Key" : "Date",
                    "Value" : "9/12/2017"
                }, 
                {
                    "Key" : "Primary Location",
                    "Value" : "Moon"
                }, 
                {
                    "Key" : "Requested By",
                    "Value" : "drei"
                }, 
                {
                    "Key" : "Secondary Location",
                    "Value" : "Canada"
                }
    ]
}
```

Say I want to find any Object where "Primary Location" is "Canada"... I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Here's my attempt:

```
var builder = Builders<Object>.Filter;
FilterDefinition<Object> filter = builder.And(
                 builder.Eq("Properties.Key", "Primary Location"),
                 builder.Eq("Properties.Value", "Canada"));
```

Essentially I'm using an And Builder for the Key and Value, however this doesn't group them together to perform the filter. It sees that there is a Key with "Primary Location" and that there is also a Value with "Canada" in the Properties 
and will return the above Object.

How should I write my filter to filter on the same Value and the Key pair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`ElemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

```
var builder = Builders<Object>.Filter;
var subbuilder = Builders<SubObject>.Filter;
FilterDefinition<Object> filter 
    = builder.ElemMatch("Properties", subbuilder.And(
           subbuilder .Eq("Key", "Primary Location"),
           subbuilder .Eq("Value", "Canada")
      ));
```

This also allows you to use the [positional operator `$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) when performing updates:

```
updateBuilder.Set("Properties.$.Value", "Test")
```

or if you're using expressions:

```
updateBuilder.Set(o => o.Properties[-1].Value, "Test")
```

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks!